# How to install Ubuntu on separate Windows partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I have two separate hard drives: `C:\` with Windows 10 and `D:\` with data. Now I want to make two partitions on `D` drive. One with 80GB for Ubuntu installation and other one with all data I have right now. I don't want to have dual boot screen at startup instead I want to *optionally* choose from which drive to boot. (By optional I mean pressing something like F10 button to choose drive without using grub.)

How can I perform such installation? Should I partition `D` drive in Windows and later install Ubuntu on that partition?

Most importantly I don't want to loose my data on `D` drive.

Output from `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA HGST HTS541010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA PLEXTOR PX-128M5 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  128GB  128GB  primary  ntfs
```

`sdb` is my `C` drive and `sda` is my `D` drive.

Comment: Are these really separate physical drives like sda, sdb or partitions like sda1, sda2, sda3 etc. Makes a big difference. Post this to confirm configuration. `sudo parted -l` from a terminal in Ubuntu live installer. Only safe way is the more advanced Something Else install option where you create & choose your partitions for Ubuntu. And good backups are required before doing anything.

Comment: @oldfred Yes those are completely separated hard drives. I edited my post. I will try to post output of `sudo parted -l` in a moment.

Comment: @oldfred: I added output of `sudo parted -l`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Even though you say sdb is C: drive, it looks like its boot partition is on sda1. Windows when not installed to drive set as boot in BIOS installs its 100MB boot partition to drive set as boot. Best to immediately copy boot files to your main install, as backup. Use Windows to shrink sda2, and run chkdsk on your d: "drive". Then use only use Something else. Not really different than standard install with manual partitioning as you have a NTFS partition to not overwrite. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks @oldfred and dn-ʞɔɐq ɹW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

1. Install Ubuntu according to the [standard instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/344926)
2. When you come to item number 8, take advanced partitioning and set the `grub` boot drive to SDB in MBR mode
3. continue a normal installation

Now, when you want to boot into Ubuntu, set the boot drive to `/dev/sdb` (probably `PLEXTOR` in your BIOS) and boot off there!

Comment: Well it actually was easy :) First I moved "System Reserved Partition" from `sda` to `sdb`. Then shrink `sda` to create free space for Ubuntu installation. Then created partitions from Ubuntu installer and set `sda` as boot drive and it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the acceptance!  Your question upvoted!  **;-)**